# apply_async() doesn't call the target function

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I was trying to run a function with multiprocessing. The callback value should be collected with a global parameter. But the target function did not run. My code is like the following:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

x = []


def func(num):
    result1 = num * 3
    result2 = num ** 2
    return [result1, result2]


def callback(result):
    global x
    x.append([result[0], result[1]])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    used_cores = 4
    pool = mp.Pool(used_cores)
    param_dict = {}
    num_task = 1000
    for i in range(used_cores):
        param_dict.update({i: list(range(i, num_task, used_cores))})
    for name, param in param_dict.items():
        pool.apply_async(func, args=(param,), callback=callback)
    print(x)
```

Comment: What's the error traceback?

Comment: @FaisalNazik There is no error, whereas the  x is still empty. That means 'func()' has not been called.